# I recently had to stop and restart a snowpipe. Since then the pipe has stopped ingesting from a stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-ingestion

I have a backlog of content on a stage, which a snowpipe until recently was ingesting.
I think it stopped ingesting when I paused the snowpipe for a while, followed by a restart; but I cannot be sure. Querying the status of the snowpipe, I see:

```
{"executionState":"RUNNING","oldestFileTimestamp":"2021-05-13T12:15:25.086Z","pendingFileCount":282,"notificationChannelName":"arn:aws:sqs:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","numOutstandingMessagesOnChannel":0,"lastReceivedMessageTimestamp":"2021-05-19T08:15:27.482Z","lastForwardedMessageTimestamp":"2021-05-19T08:15:27.531Z"}
```

The last piece of content that was ingested dates 2021-05-13 12:52:16.913.

How can I load content that landed after 2021-05-13 12:52:16.913, and how can I get the snowpipe to recommence ingesting new content as it lands?

Answer (score 0):

Try pausing the pipe again and recreating it using the CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE... option. If you do so, make sure to grant ownership etc back to the original owner (if running under a different role) along with any other permissions

Then run SELECT SYSTEM$PIPE_FORCE_RESUME( 'MY_PIPE' );

I've made many a change to pipes using this method and it hasn't failed me. Having said that we use an internal stage so I can't say for certain how it will behave with an external one